# Querying math operations vs using an update trigger on fixed column in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database-design, triggers, database-trigger

I have a table with two numeric values and I will query the difference between those two values over thousands of entries. I have two alternatives:

1. To query the difference directly like `SELECT (column_1 - column_2) as 'DIFFERENCE' FROM 'Table_Name'`
2. To have an UPDATE Trigger that automatically updates a fixed 'difference' column so I can then just query the difference column directly

As I mentioned before I will be querying potentially tens of thousands of entries so maybe option 1 would represent some kind of overload while option 2 will perform the subtraction only when necessary.

I am no expert on database performance optimization though, so maybe there's something I'm missing that somebody with more experience could point out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be a [`generated column`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) e.g.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD difference GENERATED ALWAYS AS (column_1 - column_2)
```

You can choose to add the `STORED` keyword to the end of the `ALTER TABLE` command to ensure that the value is computed once (on `INSERT` and `UPDATE` operations), or you can omit it (or add the `VIRTUAL` keyword) to indicate that the column should be computed when read. Using `VIRTUAL` is like your option 1; `STORED` is like your option 2.

Here's a small generated column [demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0fe59242056bfedb2c3d783f4c6b5e26).

Comment: Damn that was fast! and what an elegant way to do it. So in your opinion which option would be better in terms of performance? STORED or VIRTUAL?

Comment: STORED would be faster for reads, slower for writes; VIRTUAL the other way around. STORED columns require space, but can be indexed (although that's probably not of much use for differences).

Comment: Well then STORED seems like the way to go, data will be written once and never (or at most once) updated and queried several times. And I certainly need to learn more about indexing. Thank you very much for your help Nick.

Answer (score 1):

If your version of MySQL/MariaDB does not have "generated columns", then don't bother pre-computing the difference.  The cost and complication of a Trigger (or whatever) far exceeds simply recomputing the difference in every `SELECT` that needs it.  `GENERATED VIRTUAL` is probably just a fancy way of doing the difference on the fly.

In general, do not worry about the cost of any expression or builtin function call.  It is insignificant compared to the effort of locating the row, parsing it, etc.

Comment: How do I know if my MySQL version has "generated columns" or not? I tried running the code @Nick suggested but getting an error on the GENERATED keyword

Comment: (1) state which version you have.  (2) try the syntax.  (3) look it up in the manual.